# Python/PSSE Error: TypeError: an integer is required

Tags: python, psse

I am receiving an error at the end of my code when trying to load the information into PSSE. My goal is once all the data was organized how I wanted, the next step was to use that organized data and import it to PSSE. Everything before that works but once I use a PSSE API, nothing works. I get this error:
psspy.bsys(1,0,[0.0,0.0],0,[],1,[bus],0,[],0,[])
  File ".\psspy.py", line 46020, in bsys
TypeError: an integer is required.

```
import os, sys

PSSE_LOCATION = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\PTI\PSSE33\PSSBIN"
sys.path.append(PSSE_LOCATION)
os.environ['PATH'] = os.environ['PATH'] + ';' + PSSE_LOCATION
import psspy
import redirect
import csv
psspy.throwPsseExceptions = True

from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
import tkSimpleDialog
import tkMessageBox



 STUDY_CASE = 'C:\Users\RoszkowskiM\Documents\Cases\Final\ceii_Case1_SUM_2017_5050_MMWG16PF_FINAL.sav'

LOAD_GEN_DATAFILE = 'C:\Users\RoszkowskiM\Documents\CSV Files\ASTECOR_TLA.csv'

psspy.psseinit(10000)
psspy.case(STUDY_CASE)



data = list(csv.reader(open(LOAD_GEN_DATAFILE)))
mydict = {}
for row in data:
year,location,bus,change,isload = row[0:5]
# convert the types from string to Python numbers

change= float(change)
bus = int(bus)

 #If this is a year not seen before, add it to the dictionary
 if year not in mydict:
    mydict[year] = {}

 busses_in_year = mydict[year]
 if location not in busses_in_year:
     busses_in_year[location] = []

 #Add the bus to the list of busses that stop at this location
 busses_in_year[location].append((bus, change,isload))


 # assume CSV has columns as described in the doc string
 year = raw_input("Select Year of Study: ")

 location = raw_input(" Select the number associated to the TLA Pocket Location:")

 if year in mydict and location in mydict[year]:  
  busses_in_year = mydict[year]
  print("Here are all the busses at that location for that year: ")
  for bus in busses_in_year[location]:
    print(bus)


 else:
    print("Invalid Year or Location")


if isload.isdigit() and int(isload):    
    psspy.bsys(1,0,[0.0,0.0],0,[],1,[bus],0,[],0,[])
    psspy.scal_2(1,0,1,[0,0,0,0,0],[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0])
    psspy.scal_2(0,1,2,[0,1,0,1,0],[change,0.0,0,-.0,0.0,-.0,0])
```

Comment: Piece of advice. Use keyword arguments. It preserves everyone's sanity. You'll also know, and the function will also know what you're passing for what.

Comment: `psspy.bsys(sid=0, numarea=3, areas=[0, 1, 2, 3]...)` IS better

Comment: Can you give me an example? I am not too familiar with that. I am new to this forum

Comment: What @PRMoureu said is an example of using keyword args. when making your calls to psspy methods, look at the documentation and name each argument.

Comment: Not connected with your problem, but it is safer to use raw strings with all the filenames when you are using `\\` as a directory separator (as you have in PSSE_LOCATION).

Comment: Also, you should copy/paste your code exactly as it is in the .py file to your question. Then highlight the whole block and hit the '{}' button. I notice there is a lot of spacing issues.

Comment: the reason I'm not using arguments is because when I recorded on ibdev file, those parameters stayed constant. the only thing that changes was the busnumber argument

Comment: @Mike It would seem you need to pass an integer in place of one of the lists. I don't know which.

Comment: do I have to change the variable in psspy.bsys to bus.append and same thing for scale psspy.scal, change.append

Comment: @Mike I think you are confusing variables with arguments. Each argument you pass into the method psspy.bsys has a name. You can omit the name if you pass in the arguments in the order they are defined (as you have done). But when it isn't obvious what the arguments are for, it is better to specify their names. Basically, what does the list `[0.0, 0.0]` do for instance? It's the 3rd argument.

Comment: ppspy.bsys(  sid=1,usekv=0,BASEKV2=1,numarea=0,areas=1,NUMBUS=from_data_above,BUSNUM=empty_array,Character=0,BUSNAM=EMPTY_ARRAY)'

Answer (score 0):

```
for bus in busses_in_year[location]:
    print(bus)
```

What does this print? From the previous code I think `bus` is actually a `tuple`:

```
busses_in_year[location].append((bus, change, isload))
```

When you call `bsys` with `[bus]` it is using the last value of `bus` after looping through `busses_in_year[location]`. The function `bsys` expects an integer, but you're giving it the full `tuple`.

I'm not sure how to fix your code as it might not make sense to just take the last bus in the year, so you probably need to fix that first.

But if you want to properly unpack the `tuple` `(bus, change, isload)` you can do the following:

```
for bus, change, isload in busses_in_year[location]:
    print(bus)
```